# where can I get a list of stack and variant for gen_rosinstall.py

Tags: ros, installation, source, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Where can I get a list of variants or stacks per rosdistro?

In particular I would like to install desktop-pr2-full by source

rosinstall ~/ros "http://packages.ros.org/cgi-bin/gen_rosinstall.py?rosdistro=electric&variant=desktop-full"

but that does not include the pr2 stacks. is there a variant for  desktop-pr2-full?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35629/where-can-i-get-a-list-of-stack-and-variant-for-gen_rosinstall.py/) by [an314](https://answers.ros.org/users/2537/an314/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-06-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The list of variants for Electric are described in [REP 113](http://ros.org/reps/rep-0113.html), and those for Diamondback in [REP 108](http://ros.org/reps/rep-0108.html). I couldn't find a corresponding list for Fuerte.

The robot-specific variants are listed only in REP 108; the variant you are looking for is called `pr2_desktop` (also in Electric).

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2012-06-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0